# Getting error with "sudo make" command while installing aircrack-ng (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, compiling, aircrack-ng

```
XXXXX@XXXXX:~/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc2/src$ sudo make
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -fstack-protector -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude  wpaclean.o osdep/radiotap/radiotap.o -o wpaclean -Losdep -losdep -lnl-genl-3 -lnl-3  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnl-genl-3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [wpaclean] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the missing dependency *libnl-genl-3-dev*.

Install the library with the following command:

> sudo apt-get install libnl-genl-3-dev

Try *sudo make* again after installing the library.